# JSF Primefaces SelectOneMenu default value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I've read some tutorials where it was mentioned, that the only way you can set a default drop-down menu option is by ordering the options(SelectItems) list. But i am unable to do so.

The following is my XHTML:

```
<p:selectOneMenu ....>
    <p:ajax event="change" update="ordersListForm" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{Controller.memberList}"
        var="User" itemLabel="#{User.authority.fullName}"
        itemValue="#{User.authority.fullName}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

and my Bean :

```
 currentUser = loginManager.getCurrentPrincipal().getUser();
 memberList = new ArrayList<>();
 List<SiteMember> tempList = memberManager.getList();
 currentUserNN = isUserNN(currentUser);
 for (SiteMember member : tempList) {
    for (Group group : memberManager.getGroups(member.getAuthority().getUserName())) {
         if (group.getItemName().startsWith(Roles.ROLE)) {
            memberList.add(member);
         }
    }
 }
```

So the default value depends which user has logged in and from which group he belongs to.

If user belongs to group `ROLE` then his name should be the default option. If he doesn't belong to that group, the selectItems should be `memberList` ordered alphabetically.

If i can at least be shown how to make defaultUser as the default option, i can manage the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why cant you set the value attirubute of selectOneMenu as currentUser or null based on his user group and do a Collections.sort on the memberList?

Comment: sort won't work on memberList.

Comment: can you be more specific? why sort wont work?

Comment: It just sais that sort is not applicable for memberList.

Comment: please read http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/ whenever you get a chance. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Thank you Mahendar.

So, it is the only way to solve it. ?
If noone else knows how, seems I will need to go this way.

Comment: Sure there are other ways. All 10 times as complex. So please use the normal way.

Comment: normal way  you mean just to sort it as Mahendran told me.?

Maybe you r right, just seems objects sorting might be new to me, thats why I don't want it.. but if you guys say so, need to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

set the value of selectOneMenu to the current user group. If .startsWith(Roles.ROLE) true then set the value, else set the value to null.